# Can't play html5 videos in instagram app. What is its video format?

Tags: javascript, html

I can play html5 videos on all web browsers. I tried to open website link on instagram biography. I think I can't play videos on instagram in-app browser.

```
<video class="embed-responsive-item" controls id="videoId">
        <source src="videos/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="videos/1.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>

<script>
            var isChrome = !!window.chrome; 
            var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
            if( isChrome ) {
                $("#videoId").replaceWith($('<video class="video embed- 
responsive-item"  width="400" height="220" controls id="videoId"><source 
src="videos/1.webm" type="video/webm"></video>'));
            }
        </script>
```

Here is my code. I tried to use m4v,ogg,ogv,h264,mpeg but it doesn't work. How can i run videos on instagram in-app browser? Or is it possible to force to run on chrome app or other browsers?

Thanks.